# how to convert PS image to PNG and fit to page or to multiple pages

Tags: ghostscript, postscript

I am analyzing a model (compiled with -pg option so it would generate "gmon.out") and then generated a PS file (using gprof2dot.py and piping that to "dot") that charts how much time is spent in each subroutine.  When I use ghostscript to convert to a PDF it is cutting off some of the right hand side of the figure.  So I tested outputting to multiple pages, but the first page still has the right side cut off and the second page is blank.

These are the 2 commands I have tried:
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dPDFFitPage -sOutputFile=myfile.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite output.ps
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dPDFFitPage -sOutputFile=out%d.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite output.ps

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your title says you want a PNG (and you *render* a PostScript program to PNG, not "convert a PostScript image", PostScript is a programming language not an image format) but your description says you are creating PDF files. So which is it, PNG or PDF ?

Using PDFFitPage scales the **requested** media size to fit an actual (already set up, fixed) media size, since you haven't set a fixed media size on the command line, no scaling will be performed.

So, what media size are you getting, and why is that not correct ? I would 'guess' that your PostScript program does not request a media size, if it did then pdfwrite would create a PDF with the same media size.

In the absence of a media request, the pdfwrite device uses the default. Depending on your system and configuration that will most likely be either A4 or US Letter. It then reproduces the PostScript drawing program by either rendering to a bitmap, or as a PDF page description, using that media size. If the original PostScript required a different media size, then bits will be clipped.

Since you have not supplied an example its not possible for me to do more than guess of course.

However, you should probably try setting -sPAPERSIZE to something like A3. Or set a specific media size using -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS and -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS.

If you supplied an example I could probably be more specific.

It would also be a decent idea to mention what version of Ghostscript you are using too.

Comment: Thanks KenS.  Sorry I misspoke about conversion to PNG - that was my original thought then I shifted gears.  I tried adding the PAPERSIZE option as you recommended.  I am seeing a little more of the graph now but it is still cutting off.  Here is what I tried:  gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dPDFFitPage -sOutputFile=out%d.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPAPERSIZE=a3 output.ps  Let me know what might work better.  How can I determine the appropriate size to make the image fit?  The multi-page option seems smart but I see no image on the second page??  Ghostscript version is 9.07.

Comment: Well I can't tell you what the required media size is for you program without seeing the program I'm afraid. You could try the bbox device, it might give you an accurate answer. If you're gettng an empty page then most likely that's what's in the PS program. However, you might want to consider moving to something a litle less than 4 years old. The current version is 9.20 and 9.21 will be released within weeks.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I have moved away from the PDF direction and was able to convert the PS to a PNG image via ImageMagick and am manipulating that.  I do appreciate all the good info you have provided!